# How to loop over multiple fields in Django template?

Tags: django

I have models that inherit from an abstract model like this:

```
class ImprovementAbstraction(models.Model):
    needsImprovement = models.BooleanField()
    hasFallacies = models.BooleanField()
    hasEmotionalDeficiency = models.BooleanField()
    isNecessaryToObtain = models.BooleanField()
    doesAReallyCauseB = models.BooleanField()
    areAllStepsPresent = models.BooleanField()
    isCauseSufficient = models.BooleanField()
    areAllClausesIdentified = models.BooleanField()
    isCausalityCertain = models.BooleanField()
    languageIsEnglish = models.BooleanField()
    isTautologyPresent = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Assumption(MainAbstractModel, ImprovementAbstraction):
    need = models.ForeignKey(Need, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    assumption = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.assumption
```

In the template I would like to display all of the "ToImprovementAbstraction" Model fields associated with the Assumption model. Is there a way to loop over all the fields in the template, something like Assumption.ImprovementAbstractionFields.all() (made up code)?

Answer (score 1):

I use the built-in `vars()` method for that.

For example, you have an Assumption object:

```
assumptionObject = .models.Assumption.objects.get(pk=1)
```

If you use `vars()` method with that query object like this:

```
vars(assumptionObject)
```

it will return a dictionary containing all the field names and values as a Python dictionary.

If you only want the field names you can use it like this:

```
vars(assumptionObject).keys()
```

**EDIT:** I should warn you that, if you use `vars()` on a query object, the returned dictionary will contain a `django.db.models.base.ModelState` object stored in a key called `_state`. If you're going to use the values in a `for` loop or something, you should put an exception for that.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what your desired outcome is, but this is the basic approach to query data from the database and render the html:

You will first have to query the data from the database like so:

**Views.py**

```
def search(request):
    queryset = ToImprovementAbstraction.objects.all()
    context = {
        'queryset': queryset
    }
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

Then you can use the data to render your template like so:

**your_template.html**

```
{% for item in queryset %}

<p>{{ item.needsImprovement }}</p>
[...]
[...]

{% endfor %}
```

If oyu have multiple models you can make multiple queries to use one/many-to-many fields in your models to link them straight away.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear in my post, sorry. What I need is this: I have multiple models that inherint from the ImprovementAbstraction model, because they all need to have the same BooleanField fields. My desired outcome is displaying all the fields of the Assumption model that have been added to it from ImprovementAbstraction model (bc of inheritance) in one for loop, in order to avoid having to type the same code over and over again.

Comment: Why can't you check the values_list() in Django for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

get the assumption object in view and render the ImprovementAbstraction through foreign key. for example:

```
def get_item():
  queryset = Assumption.objects.all()

return render(request, 'template.html', {'queryset': queryset})
```

Now in your template you can access the data this way

```
{% for query in queryset %}
  {{query.need.needImprovement}}
  {{query.need.hasFallacies}}
  {{...}}

 {% endfor %}
```

This way you can display everything in one loop. Hope this gets you some idea.